# Onlick Not Firing with Touchscreen Events

Tags: javascript, onclick, touchscreen

On touchscreen and in the Chrome device simulator with the touch tool, my onclick listeners are not firing.

**Here is the code:**

```
<div onclick="image1()" class="image-box"><img src="example.png"></div>
```

**Then, it runs this JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('main-image').setAttribute("src", "example2.png");

document.getElementById('image-1').setAttribute("class", "active")
```